# How to modify the embedded manifest of an Inno Setup Installer?

Tags: installation, manifest, inno-setup, administrator

I have an Inno Setup installer that worked fine on my machine (Win 7 32-bit), but did not work at all on a test machine (also Win 7 32-bit).  After some investigation, I found that the reason is that there is something going wrong when the UAC is set to anything which is not ***Never notify me***.  However, if I right click on the installer, and select ***Run as Administrator***, the installer works fine.

I then tried to modify the embedded manifest of the installer (methods described below), so that it will always run as admin, but this is not working as I wished.  I have obtained the original manifest using the command

```
mt.exe -inputresource:installer.exe -out:installer.exe.manifest
```

I, then, opened the extracted manifest using a text editor and changed the line

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
```

I then, tried to apply the resulting manifest, by running the command

```
mt.exe -manifest installer.exe.manifest -updateresource:installer.exe;#1
```

but the manifest tool gave me the error

> mt.exe : manifest authoring error c1010001: Values of attribute "level" not equal in different manifest snippets.

I also tried changing the command to

```
mt.exe -manifest installer.exe.manifest -outputresource:installer.exe;#1
```

but this caused the entire installer to be overwritten by nothing more than the resources (i.e. the actual installer was lost).

I also tried opening the installer executable using Visual Studio (Resource Editor), modified the manifest and saved the file, but this gave the same result as the second *mt.exe* command I used.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong, or if I am missing out on something ?

Comment: If you do the "run as admin" or change the manifest then it will break some on Inno's functionality. Inno (should) elevate itself and relies on having the initial EXE run unelevated. If you explain your actual problem with the setup, I can guarentee there is a better solution.

Comment: Note to others: This question was also asked on the [Inno newsgroups](http://news.jrsoftware.org/read/article.php?id=96418&group=jrsoftware.innosetup#96418) with information on the actual problem.

Comment: @Deanna, good point! And the answer is probably there - to use the newest version of InnoSetup since I personally haven't noticed that when I don't explicitly specify the `PrivilegesRequired` to something else than `admin` the admin elevation wouldn't be asked.

Comment: @Deanna - doing "run as admin" did not break anything, or at least nothing that is needed by this particular installer.  The setup is failing when it is being elevated.  I am being presented with a dialog box, saying

`The following command-line argument is not valid:`
`/SPAWNWND=$1A0292`

Also, I am using the latest version of Inno Setup (5.5.0).

Comment: It WILL break all the `...AsOriginalUser` and `PostInstall` functionality as per my asnwer. As for the Inno problem, it's pointing to a corrupt setup but the question on the newsgroup should get an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't modify the manifest of the resulting Inno setup as Inno does any elevation it needs for the [`PrivilegesRequired`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_privilegesrequired.htm) directive.

If you do modify the manifest, or manually do "Run as Administrator" then it will break all the `...AsOriginalUser` functionality, most importantly, the [`postinstall` flag](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm#postinstall).

`mt.exe` and similar resource editors are also very likely to strip the setup data from the setup file as it's appended to the end of the binary.